# Update Model variable without refreshing Page ASP.Net MVC RAZOR Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to Update my model property from my view, i know its not recommended. 
What i did is i made a hidden control like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.CurrentIndex);
```

and i set value for the control using Jquery like

```
$('#CurrentIndex').val(index);
```

It is not enough to update my model.CurrentIndex property from view? Am I missing something. Please advice me with this code or guide me in a new direction where i can achieve what I desire.

Comment: Why the downvote, Please tell me what wrong in my question, before downvoting

Comment: do you want to save the updated value of the model in backend ?? if yes then you can use ajax.

Comment: No i want changed value to be set in my @Model.CurrentIndex so i can use that for some other calculations in the Razor page it self

Comment: You can change any value that has been rendered to the browser with JavaScript. You did the right thing there

Comment: But the changed value is not set in my Model Property, Its always showing Zero as the type is int.

Comment: How do you get the value of index? Can you log it an be sure it is not 0

Comment: int index=0; When the user clicks next button  index++;  thats how i get the value. The value is in client side, and i need the value to be set in my model property. @model.property=index; cant be set so i used @html.hidden() and set the value in jquery so it will get affected in the model as well. But its not working.

Comment: Can you show the code or use something like `index = index + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the page is rendered the `@Model.CurrentIndex` changed to the hidden field has id is `CurrentIndex` .so if you want to use this value again, get value using id `#CurrentIndex` in jquery.

Check this demo as per your requirement, when the button clicks value increase. (value stored in the hidden field)

```
<input type="button" onclick="setIndex()" value="next">
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.CurrentIndex)

<div id="showdiv">
    <input type="text" id ="newindex">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function setIndex(index) {
      var data=$('#CurrentIndex').val();
      data++;
      $('#CurrentIndex').val(data);
      $('#newindex').val(data);
    }

</script>
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YkLOTh)